MapStruct mapper is null in MapperImpl class in SpringBoot test
The project builds successfully but tests fail with the error: Cannot invoke "io.github.jspinak.brobot.app.database.mappers.PatternMapper.map(io.github.jspinak.brobot.datatypes.primitives.image.Pattern)" because "this.patternMapper" is null
The error comes in line 71 of StateImageMapperImpl, a class created at compiletime by MapStruct. Lines 69-72 are:
List<PatternEntity> list1 = new ArrayList<PatternEntity>( list.size() );
for ( Pattern pattern : list ) {
    list1.add( patternMapper.map( pattern ) );
}

I've read the related questions but none of the answers fixed the issue. For example, the Lombok dependency is before the MapStruct dependency in my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '8.6'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

// module-specific configurations
group = 'io.github.jspinak.brobot'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '20'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':library') // Dependency on the library module
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // JUnit Jupiter for testing
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.2'
    // Spring Boot Starter Test for Spring Boot testing support
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' 
    implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.2.224'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
    // database
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.2.224'

    implementation('com.sikulix:sikulixapi:2.0.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-nop'
    }
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.12'

    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.10'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.kwhat:jnativehook:2.2.2'

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

// Configure MapStruct compiler arguments
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring'
    ]
}

StateImageMapper uses PatternMapper, which uses other mapper classes.
package io.github.jspinak.brobot.app.database.mappers;

import io.github.jspinak.brobot.app.database.entities.StateImageEntity;
import io.github.jspinak.brobot.datatypes.state.stateObject.stateImage.StateImage;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {PatternMapper.class})
public interface StateImageMapper {
    StateImageMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(StateImageMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "patterns", source = "patterns")
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    StateImageEntity map(StateImage stateImage);

    @Mapping(target = "patterns", source = "patterns")
    StateImage map(StateImageEntity stateImageEntity);
}

package io.github.jspinak.brobot.app.database.mappers;

import io.github.jspinak.brobot.app.database.entities.PatternEntity;
import io.github.jspinak.brobot.datatypes.primitives.image.Pattern;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {SearchRegionsMapper.class, MatchHistoryMapper.class,
        PositionMapper.class, AnchorsMapper.class, ImageMapper.class})
public interface PatternMapper {
    PatternMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PatternMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "searchRegions", target = "searchRegions")
    @Mapping(source = "matchHistory", target = "matchHistory")
    @Mapping(source = "position", target = "position")
    @Mapping(source = "anchors", target = "anchors")
    @Mapping(source = "image", target = "image")
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    PatternEntity map(Pattern pattern);

    @Mapping(source = "searchRegions", target = "searchRegions")
    @Mapping(source = "matchHistory", target = "matchHistory")
    @Mapping(source = "position", target = "position")
    @Mapping(source = "anchors", target = "anchors")
    @Mapping(source = "image", target = "image")
    Pattern map(PatternEntity patternEntity);
}

The project is open-source and found at https://github.com/jspinak/brobot .
